# Visual C++ 2015 <printf> gives right hand sided column while <fprintf> centers all values

Tags: c++, printf

Maybe a simple problem: Visual C++ 2015  gives right-hand sided column on the screen (as it should be), while  centers (!)all double values in the column. All left-hand format and 0 filled format work properly.
How could I get with fprintf a right-hand sided column ?

```
int main()
{
int row;
double bb;
FILE *a;
a = fopen("c:\\users\\joe\\desktop\\TEST100_out.txt", "w+");
for (row = 0; row < 30; row++)
{
bb = 12345678.90;
if (row > 10)
{
bb = 5678.90;
}
printf ("%15.2f\n", bb);        // right-hand sided
fprintf (a, "%15.2f\n", bb);    // centered, but should be right-hand
}
fclose(a);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, in your first sentence "... while **fprintf** centers (!)all double values" (i.e. did you omit the fprintf there)?

Comment: @joe, can you add both outputs of this example? To make it more clear what is happening, you could replace all spaces with a visible character like a dot.

Comment: Hmm, no, this surely has something to do with what you do with the .txt file next.   Like printing it or opening it in a text editor.  With a proportionally spaced font whose width for a space is less than the width for a digit.

Comment: printf for stdout works perfectly right-sided as it should. Only fprintf for the txt file is centered. The Format seems to be ok. So is probably the txt file .. Hans: how could I modify the txt file .. ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Hans was right with his comment. fprintf correctly prints right-hand sided in the txt file only with the "Lucida Console" txt font. Thanks to all your comments !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difference Between *fprintf* and *printf*

- `fprintf` writes formatted text to the output stream you specify.
- `printf` is equivalent to writing fprintf(stdout, ...) and writes formatted text to wherever the standard output stream is currently pointing.

How could I get with *fprintf* a right-hand sided column ?

- Putting `%15.2f` the right-hand side of the numbers would be the 15th character to the right of the previous column.So try increasing the value so as it pushes to the right.